# math.round number format

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script on my site that makes conversion weights. The Math.round function works normally, but I need to format the "result" to appear as follows: ex. 1.000,000. Today this number appears as 1000.000. Does anyone know how to do? I tried a few things number_format but could not. Follow the code below:

```
<script>
        function convert() {

            var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value,
                measurement_from = document.getElementById("measurement_from"),
                measurement_from_name = measurement_from.options[measurement_from.selectedIndex].text,
                measurement_from_type = measurement_from.options[measurement_from.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-type'),
                measurement_from_value = measurement_from.options[measurement_from.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-value'),
                measurement_to = document.getElementById("measurement_to"),
                measurement_to_name = measurement_to.options[measurement_to.selectedIndex].text,
                measurement_to_type = measurement_to.options[measurement_to.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-type'),
                measurement_to_value = measurement_to.options[measurement_to.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-value'),
                ingredient = document.getElementById("ingredient"),
                ingredient_name = ingredient.options[ingredient.selectedIndex].text,
                ingredient_density = ingredient.options[ingredient.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-density'),
                total_volume,
                result,
                result_text,
                result_div = document.getElementById("result");

                if (measurement_from_type == 'weight')
                    total_volume = amount * measurement_from_value / ingredient_density;
                else 
                    total_volume = amount * measurement_from_value;

                if (measurement_to_type == 'weight')
                    result = total_volume / measurement_to_value * ingredient_density;
                else
                    result = total_volume / measurement_to_value;

                result = Math.round(result * 1000) / 1000;
                result_text = result + ' ' + measurement_to_name ;
                while( result_div.firstChild ) {
                    result_div.removeChild( result_div.firstChild );
                }
                result_div.appendChild( document.createTextNode(result_text) );


        }
    </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider tagging this `javascript` rather than `php`, because that's what the code you've posted is

Comment: The result is totally ok, Math.round(1234.5678124 * 1000) / 1000 results in 1234.5678 – So what you want is a rounding and after that a string-formatting that formats the number in a printable format

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, as I am new to programming, I'm still a little lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). Example:

```
var number = 35000000;

console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }));
// outputs "35.000.000,00"
```

You can choose the localization you prefer, by changing 'de-DE'.
On your code:

```
result = Math.round(result * 1000) / 1000; 
// are you sure you don't mean to include / 1000 inside the round? 
result = result.toLocaleString('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
...
```

Comment: I guess you feel lazy, here:
    `result = Math.round(result * 1000) / 1000;`
    `// are you sure you don't mean to include / 1000 inside the round?`
    `result = result.toLocaleString('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });`
    ...

Comment: I was not lazy, the truth is that I know very little programming, I'm more curious.

Anyway I appreciate the help of all and apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: I edited my answer, because I can't use linebreaks in comments. 
If my answer fixes your problem, please accept it as the right answer :)

Comment: I just signal your help as correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'continental style' numbers , like 1.234.567,89 have a look at php Locales.